# Use LLDB with brewed python - OS X

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, python-3.x, lldb

I'm currently trying to get the `LLDB python module` working on my MacBook.
OS X already shippes with a python version, but there are many reasons to choose *Homebrew* python over the preinstalled one ([see this](http://blog.manbolo.com/2014/09/27/use-python-effectively-on-os-x)).

I'm using the *Homebrew* python version, but this versions doesn't know the location to the `LLDB Library`.

```
Matthias@MacBookPro ~$ which python
/usr/local/bin/python
Matthias@MacBookPro ~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named lldb
>>>
```

Same with `python3`:

```
Matthias@MacBookPro ~$ which python3
/usr/local/bin/python3
Matthias@MacBookPro ~$ python3
Python 3.5.1 (default, Dec  7 2015, 21:59:10) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lldb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'lldb'
>>>
```

Now I added this to my `.bash_profile`:

```
 export PYTHONPATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/Python:${PYTHONPATH}"
```

This is the location to the preinstalled `LLDB module` which the preinstalled python uses (this actually works fine with the preinstalled python located under `/usr/bin/python` - `python3` isn't preinstalled I think).

But with the *brewed* one I get this:

```
Matthias@MacBookPro ~$ python
Python 2.7.11 (default, Dec  5 2015, 14:44:53) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.1.76)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import lldb
Fatal Python error: PyThreadState_Get: no current thread
Abort trap: 6
```

What can I do to make the `LLDB module` work with the brewed python? I'm really hoping that anyone before me experienced this and found a solution.

Comment: Judging by [this PR](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/pull/36229), you may be able to get it working by installing `llvm` through Homebrew.

Comment: @robertklep Doesn't seem to work neither.

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? I suspect not - it seems like it's still basically impossible to get an lldb python module for use with brewed python.